# calling asp.net mvc with jQuery Load from asp.net webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms, jquery-load

I have two sites one is written in asp.net webforms and the other one is written in asp.net mvc 2.
I have a page in webforms wich uses jQuery Load to get data from both projects.

Code from the page in asp.net webforms:

```
$("#divFeedsPorTagMVC").load('http://localhost:50001/InfoMVC/?tag=java', function (){});

$("#divFeedsPorTagWebForms").load('http://localhost:50000/InfoWebForms.aspx?tag=java', function () {}});
```

Divs in aspx page:

```
<div id="divFeedsPorTagWebForms" ></div>
<div id="divFeedsPorTagMVC" ></div>
```

The jQuery call to WebForms works well and fills the "divFeedsPorTagWebForms" with the HTML i need.
The jQuery call to MVC2 enters to the Index function of the InfoMVCController(debug mode), shows that the tag param is being passed well, but doesn´t fill the "divFeedsPorTagMVC" div with the HTML it's suppossed to return.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

**EDIT**
Controller:

```
 public class InfoMVCController : Controller
    {
        private ServicioSORSS.ServicioSORSSClient _srvSORSS = new ServicioSORSSClient();

        //
        // GET: /InfoWebForms/

        public ActionResult Index(string tag)
        {
            return View(_srvSORSS.ObtenerFeedsPorTag(tag));
        }

    }
```

If I just copy the URL and paste it in the nav bar of firefox it does return all the data i need!

Comment: Have you tried using something like HttpFox or Fiddler or some other tool to see what response you're getting?

Comment: What do you get if you just load `http://localhost:50001/InfoMVC/?tag=java` in a browser?

Comment: Can you post the controller code for the MVC action method that you are calling?

Comment: updated my question to answer all your questions!

Comment: I think that the issue is that the webforms app does not know how to handle the ActionResult and you may need to return the result as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a problem with [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You browser isn't allowing the load, because it's coming from a different site.

Look into the standard [$.ajax() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and use `jsonp` as the dataType.

It will be something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:50001/InfoMVC/?tag=java",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        $('#divFeedsPorTagMVC').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: have to tell you i didn´t know anything about this! and you´re right, that was my problem! i can´t use $.ajax because i´m doing a research about jquery load! i ended up publishing each site inside localhost this way:  **http://localhost/webforms/** and **http://localhost/mvc/** and that way i can call the jquery load without any problems! Thanks for your help.